# Linux Visual Code 'no space left on device'

Tags: platformio

I am running Linux Mint 21.1, and I am running VSCode with PlatformIO extension. My project folder is located on my server which I access with Samba. This setup works fine on Windows, with one registry change.

Whenever I try to compile code, I get an error:

```
Compiling .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiSTA.cpp.o
/tmp/ccE4gY8E.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccE4gY8E.s:3187: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN11EEPROMClassC2Ev of .pio/build/ESP32/libed2/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/ccE4gY8E.s:3187: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/libed2/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/libed2/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/cczanPYc.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cczanPYc.s:292: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN9WiFiClass9printDiagER5Print of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFi.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/cczanPYc.s:292: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFi.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFi.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/cc6b9P0Z.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc6b9P0Z.s:1674: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._Z18wifi_softap_configP13wifi_config_tPKcS2_h16wifi_auth_mode_thhbt of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiAP.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/cc6b9P0Z.s:1674: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiAP.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiAP.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/cc5AEBw4.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc5AEBw4.s:1583: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN9WiFiMultiD2Ev of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/cc5AEBw4.s:1583: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/ccPCAQ20.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccPCAQ20.s:5420: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN10WiFiClient7connectE9IPAddresst of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp.o: 'No space left on device'
/home/rj/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/as: BFD (crosstool-NG esp-2021r2-patch5) 2.35.1.20201223 assertion fail /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/binutils/bfd/elf.c:3163
```

The server should have plenty of space, as should my laptop. I am not really sure what directory it says lacks space, or how to solve the problem. I am also somewhat inexperienced with Linux, and coding in general. Any suggestions to how I might solve this?

Comment: This isn't really a good question for SO, more for superuser, but try `df -h`

Comment: Or askubuntu. Maybe I should try to post there instead if this isn't the place